# How to make this code scanf a sequence of integers until I enter negative integer? I thaught %u won't take negative integers

Tags: c

I want that while loop ends when I enter number that's not unsigned
(lower than zero), but that  just not happen until I type some symbol
on my keyboard (letter etc.) and then debugging stops. Can anyone help
me, please?

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define ALLOC_CHECK(p) if (!(p)) puts("Neuspesna alokacija"), exit(1)

bool is_palindrome(unsigned x)
{
    unsigned i, j, n = 8 * sizeof x; // Broj bita unsigned x

    for (i = 1 << n-1, j = 1; i > j; i >>= 1, j <<= 1)
        if (!(x & i) != !(x & j)) // Proverava da li su biti logicki razliciti
            return false;

    return true;
}

int main(void)
{
    unsigned size = 10, n = 0, i;
    unsigned *a = malloc(size * sizeof(*a));
    ALLOC_CHECK(a);

    puts("Enter a sequence of integers:");
    while (scanf("%u", &a[n++]))
        if (n == size) {
            size *= 2;
            a = realloc(a, size * sizeof(*a));
            ALLOC_CHECK(a);
        }

    // Moze i da se skrati na pravu duzinu sa a = realloc(a, n * sizeof(*a));

    puts("Binary palindromes are:");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        if (is_palindrome(a[i]))
            printf("%u ", a[i]);

    free(a);
}
```

Comment: The return value from `scanf` tells you nothing about the data value that was entered.

Comment: It might seem strange, but `%u` will accept negative integers as input. E.e. `-2` is a perfectly valid input sequence for `%u`. The integer value will be converted to `unsigned int` using the usual rules.

Comment: #another macro abuse

Comment: Note that if `scanf()` reports EOF, your loop continues.  That's unlikely to lead to happiness.  Personally, if the body of a loop contains an `if`, I put braces around the body of the loop.  It reduces the risk of confusion.  Also, the idiom `old_ptr = realloc(old_ptr, new_size)` is a recipe for memory leakage on allocation failure.  Use `new_ptr = realloc(old_ptr, new_size); if (new_ptr != 0) old_ptr = new_ptr; else …handle error…`.

Answer (score 3):

> I want that while loop ends when I enter number that's not unsigned (lower than zero).

Think of input as text that needs testing.

```
// input examples
"-12345678901234567890" should stop the loop
"-1" should stop the loop
"123" should be read successfully as an `unsigned`
"  +123" should be read successfully as an `unsigned`
"12345678901234567890" is outside `unsigned` range and results are TBD
"abc" is not `unsigned`, so should stop loop.
"" is not `unsigned`, so should stop loop.
" 123 xyz"  is not `unsigned`, so should stop loop.
etc.
```

Using `fgets()` is more robust, yet let us try a `scanf()` solution.

> I thought `%u` won't take negative integers

`scanf("%u",...` will take input like `"-123"` and convert that to an `unsigned`.  So code is needed to detect a `-`

Following will not detect overflow nor white-space only lines nor consume text after a `-`.

```
// consume leading white space, look for `-` (various approaches)
int n = 0;
scanf(" -%n", &n);
if (n > 0) exit_loop();  // `-` found

unsigned x;
if (scanf("%u", &x) != 1) exit_loop();  // non numeric input
// Success, use `x`
...
```

In an *ugly* while loop that use `" %1[-]"` to look for a `-`

```
char minus[2];
// while a search for `-` failed and `unsigned` succeeded 
while (scanf(" %1[-]", minus) != 1 && scanf("%u", &x) == 1) {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by @AnT, a negative value is a valid input for `scanf("%u" ...`

I suggest to use a signed type `long` in conjunction with `fgets` and `strtol` in order to catch negative values:

```
puts("Enter a sequence of integers:");
char str[32], *ptr;
long val;
while (fgets(str, sizeof str, stdin)) {
    val = strtol(str, &ptr, 10);
    if ((*ptr == '\n') && (val >= 0)) {
        a[n++] = strtoul(str, NULL, 10);
    } else break;
    if (n == size) {
        size *= 2;
        a = realloc(a, size * sizeof(*a));
        ALLOC_CHECK(a);
    }
}
```

Comment: Minor concern: Input  text with `unsigned` value in the range `LONG_MAX...ULONG_MAX` will convert to `LONG_MAX`.

Comment: @chux, sorry but I don't get you (_will convert to LONG_MAX_), are you suggesting to check for a range between `0` and `UINT_MAX`?

Comment: Example: `UINT_MAX` may exceed `LONG_MAX`.  With 32-bit `int/unsigned/long`, valid input like `"4000000000"` will assign `val = 2147483647` or `LONG_MAX`.  Perhaps not a concern for OP, just some edge conditions.

Comment: Example `printf("%u %ld\n", UINT_MAX, LONG_MAX);` --> 4294967295 2147483647

Comment: I see, in this case we need to use `strtoul` isn't it?, but then: how to catch negative values?

Comment: Keep `strtol()` for the negative test and use `a[n++] = strtoul(str, &ptr, 10);`.  Works as long as the converted value does not exceed `UINT_MAX`. - That last case is something OP has not specified yet.

Comment: Nice!! I appreciate your always valuable help :)

Answer (score 0):

Negative numbers are considered valid input for `%u`.

This is what C90 says about `%u`:

> Matches an optionally signed decimal integer, whose format is the same as expected for the subject sequence of the `strtoul` function with the value `10` for the base argument. The corresponding argument shall be a pointer to unsigned integer.

And it says this about `strtoul()`:

> the expected form of the subject sequence is a sequence of letters and digits representing an integer with the radix specified by `base`, optionally preceded by a plus or minus sign, but not including an integer suffix.

...

> If the subject sequence begins with a minus sign, the value resulting from the conversion is negated.

---

Instead you should read the input as an `int` and then check whether it is positive or negative. i.e:

```
scanf("%d", &a[n]);
if(a[n++] >= 0)
```

And yes, that reduces the range of positive number you can input to half but that's the way to go about it.

Other than that you can get the input as `char` and then parse them yourself which isn't that hard to be honest. something like

```
unsigned int num = 0;
while(isdigit(c = getchar()))
  num = num * 10 + c;
```

as a very simple solution. of course you can check for an optional `+` at the beginning and probably accept other bases and much more but this was just a simple code to show you the idea.

Answer (score 0):

> I want that while loop ends when I enter number that's not unsigned (lower than zero).

`scanf("%u", ...)` will read text `"-123"` in and successfully convert that to an `unsigned`.

---

A fairly safe assumption is `UINT_MAX <= INTMAX_MAX`.  In other words, the widest signed integer covers the `unsigned` range.  On rare machines, this is not true - as allowed by C.

Use `scanf()` (which lacks OF protection)  or `fgets()/strtoimax()`

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#if UINT_MAX > INTMAX_MAX
  #error range issue
#endif

intmax_t big_input;
while (scanf("%jd", &big_input) == 1 && (big_input >= 0)) {
  if (big_input > UINT_MAX) TBD_Code();
  a[n++] = (unsigned) big_input;
  // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
    char buff[20];       
    while (1)
    {
        do
        {
             printf("Enter number: ");
             fgets(buff, 20, stdin);
        } while (!sscanf(buff, "%u", &a_a));
        if(a[n] == (0UL - 1UL)) break;    
        if (++n == size) {
            size *= 2;
            a = realloc(a, size * sizeof(*a));
            ALLOC_CHECK(a);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can't tell whether there's a value to look at in `a[n]` if you don't check the return value from `scanf()`.

Comment: And what happens on EOF?